# VBA Extending a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks. On the first I use VBA to find a cell;

```
Dim un_pro as range
Set un_pro = ws.cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlup).Offset(Rowoffset:=1)
```

On the second I find the size of a range:

```
Dim me_lrow as long
me_lrow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlup).Row
```

I want to extend un_pro to be as large as me_lrow, but cannot figure it out. The last thing I tried was creating a new range:

```
Dim un_cat as range
un_cat = un_pro & me_lrow
```

I think my thought process is correct but I'm blanking on the syntax.

Comment: You're looking for [resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to create a range that runs from the row after the last used row (say row 5) in column B and has number of rows defined by the last used row in column A (say row 10). The desired result is the range B6:B15. In that case the following works.

```
Sub ExtendRange()

Dim un_pro As Range, ws As Worksheet, me_lrow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set un_pro = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(Rowoffset:=1)

me_lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set un_pro = un_pro.Resize(me_lrow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Dim un_cat As Range
Set un_cat = Union(unoiuun_pro, me_lrow)
```